# Unable to use few Selenium commands while writing scripts

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-ide

There are some Selenium commands that I am unable to use in a script that I'm writing and I do not have any idea as to whether I am missing an import of required library files or packages.

For example - `selenium.browserbot`, `selenium.waitForElementPresent`.

I am using Selenium IDE to record the script and working in Eclispe Junit platform.

Answer (score 0):

Use isElementPresent instead of waitForElementPresent.

Comment: An anonymous user tried to edit this to add "Command isElementPresent is not available. This answer is wrong". I've no idea whether that's true or not, but it shouldn't be in an edit but may be worth noting that someone suggested this to be the case.